# Why parallel version is slower than sequential version

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

```
def wordsearch():
    final=[]
    with open('./words.txt', 'r') as f:
        k = f.readlines()
        for i in k:
            s = str(i)
            s = s.replace('\n','')
            if s == s[::-1]:
                final.append(s)
    return final
%timeit wordsearch()
```

Here I get 165ms +- 3.78 ms

```
def is_palin(k, limit):
        final=[]
        for i in range(limit[0], limit[1]):
            s=str(k[i])
            s = s.replace('\n','')
            if s == s[::-1]:
                final.append(s)
        return final
def wordsearch():
    final = []
    with open('./words.txt', 'r') as f:
        k = list(f.readlines())
        x = 100000
    
        lengths = [(i,i+x) for i in range(0, len(k)-x, x)]
        lengths.append((len(k)-x, len(k)))
    
        par_palin = partial(is_palin, k)
    
        with mp.Pool(processes=5) as p:
            k = p.map(par_palin, lengths)
            return k
%timeit wordsearch()
```

Here i get 780ms +- 81 ms

My question: Why is my Parallel code so many times slower than the sequential? Is there a way to speed it up?
I have tried many combinations of `x` value and changing the number of `processes` in `Pool`. Above is the best result I am getting.

Note: `is_palin` function is checking if a word is a palindrome and appending it to a list. `x` is the value for slicing the list.

Comment: Maybe because it has substantially more code?

Comment: How many lines are there in words.txt? If there are fewer than 100_000 then you will only create one Process and, in that case, the additional time you're seeing will be consumed by the overhead(s) of creating separate processes. Even so, *is_palin* is likely to be very short-lived and therefore probably not worthy of multi-processing

Comment: First, there is overhead in creating processes for your pool. Second there is overhead in queuing up tasks for your processes to process. Third, there is overhead in returning results from one process to another. Your worker function (`is_palin`) has to be sufficiently expensive (CPU-intensive) so that what you gain by running it in parallel more than offsets all the additional overhead I have just described. In your case it clearly does not. And if you could shave some time off that 165 ms, what would you do with that saved time? By the way, you have indentation errors in both code samples.

Comment: for reference, on my machine: it takes anywhere from 150 to 500 ms just for a process to start up.

Comment: Thanks, for the response, the word document has 466550 lines, each line has one word.

Comment: @Aaron  and @Booboo I think it could be as you guys described because i cant get any speed up not matter what i change in the code. The indentation errors in `def wordsearch` i have fixed them. Thank you.

Comment: Just for fun... you can double the performance of your single-threaded code by using `for s in [line.rstrip() for line in f]:` and briefly checking if the first and last letters are the same to reject strings quickly `if (s[0] == s[-1]) and (s == s[::-1])`